# How to calculate loan

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

There's a problem in my programming. The monthly payment and total payments are not adding up in the output. Meaning it stays the same like this

```
 Monthly Payment            Total Payment
   $188.71                   $11322.74
```

Here's the sample of my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Loan Amount: ");
    double loanAmount=in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Number of Years: ");
    int years=in.nextInt();

    double annualInterestRate = 5;
    double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 1200;
    double monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate /
            (1-1 / Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, years * 12));
    double totalPayment =  monthlyPayment * 12 * years;

    double i = 5.0;
    int lastMonth = years * 12;
    int month = 1;

    while ( i <= 8.0)
    {
    monthlyPayment = (int) (monthlyPayment * 100) / 100.0;
    totalPayment = (int) (totalPayment * 100) / 100.0;
    i +=0.125;
    System.out.println("Interest Rate      Monthly Payment            Total Payment");
    System.out.println(i + "%                  $" + monthlyPayment + "                   $" + totalPayment);
    }
}
```

---

The output must be like this

```
Loan Amount: 10000
Number of Years: 5
Interest Rate Monthly Payment Total Payment
5.000%        188.71           11322.74
5.125%        189.29           11357.13
5.250%        189.86           11391.59 
.... 
7.875%        202.17           12129.97
8.000%        202.76           12165.84
```

but what happened to my output is

```
Interest Rate Monthly Payment Total Payment
5.000%        188.71          11322.74
5.125%        188.71          11322.74
5.250%        188.71          11322.74
....
7.875%        188.71          11322.74
8.000%        188.71          11322.74
```

Comment: Can you please explain, what exactly the problem is and what you want? The code looks good to me.

Comment: @ctst the output of monthly payment and total payments are not going up. it stays the same. just the same. same number

Comment: it works, what's the problem?

Comment: totalPayment = (int) (totalPayment * 100) / 100.0;
That does not make much sense.

Comment: @gurghet nope it does not. look at the output of monthly payment and total payment. it stays the same. The output must be like this 

Loan Amount: 10000 [ENTER]
Number of Years: 5 [ENTER]
Interest Rate Monthly Payment Total Payment
5.000% 188.71 11322.74
5.125% 189.29 11357.13
5.250% 189.86 11391.59
....
7.875% 202.17 12129.97
8.000% 202.76 12165.84

but what happened to my output is 


Interest Rate Monthly Payment Total Payment
5.000% 188.71 11322.74
5.125% 188.71 11322.74
5.250% 188.71 11322.74
....
7.875% 188.71 11322.74
8.000% 188.71 11322.74

Comment: Maybe the mistake is, that you never use your variable `i` anywhere in your `while`-loop?

Comment: You multiply by 100 then divide by 100... of course they stay the same

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic, since the mistake is shallow and will not to help any future readers.

Comment: @ctst please dont. this may helps them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be doing the correct calculations, but just outside of the loop, which can just be a for-loop.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Loan Amount: ");
double loanAmount = in.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Number of Years: ");
int years = in.nextInt();

// Unused variables...
// int lastMonth = years * 12;
// int month = 1;

for (double annualInterestRate = 5.0; annualInterestRate <= 8.0; annualInterestRate += 0.125) {
    double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 1200;
    double monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate /
            (1 - 1 / Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, years * 12));
    double totalPayment = monthlyPayment * 12 * years;

    System.out.println("Interest Rate\tMonthly Payment\tTotal Payment");
    System.out.printf("%.03f%%\t$%.02f\t$%.02f\n", annualInterestRate, monthlyPayment, totalPayment);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much @cricket_007 such a beautiful soul :)

Comment: yes it is. thank you so much. (from me and for those who will encounter this question in the future) :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your block of code here is the cause for the sample run having the same numbers repeat over and over again in the Monthly Payment and Total Payment categories

```
while ( i <= 8.0)
{
    monthlyPayment = (int) (monthlyPayment * 100) / 100.0;
    totalPayment = (int) (totalPayment * 100) / 100.0;
    i +=0.125;
    System.out.println("Interest Rate      Monthly Payment            Total Payment");
    System.out.println(i + "%                  $" + monthlyPayment + "                   $" + totalPayment);
}
```

I'm guessing the the for each run of the while loop the totalPayment and monthlyPayment need to be effected by the changing rate i

In order to have the these payments change as the rate increases you will need to incorporate a new calculation into the loop such as

```
monthlyPayment = loanAmount * i / (1-1 / Math.pow(1 + i, years * 12));
```

This set of code was created earlier outside the loop and can be moved inside for a more condensed amount.

Answer (score 0):

You should mention the intention of your code. I think it is to print the monthly payment and total payment of a loan at different interest rates.

This will answer exactly that question:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Loan Amount: ");
    double loanAmount = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Number of Years: ");
    int years = in.nextInt();

    double annualInterestRate = 5;

    double i = 5.0;
    int lastMonth = years * 12;
    int month = 1;

    while (i <= 8.0) {
        double monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate + i) / 1200;
        double monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate / (1 - 1 / Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, years * 12));
        double totalPayment = monthlyPayment * 12 * years;
        System.out.println("Interest Rate      Monthly Payment            Total Payment");
        System.out.println(i + "%                  $" + monthlyPayment + "                   $" + totalPayment);
        i += 0.125;
    }
}
```

The answer is that you have do recalculate monthlyPayment and totalPayment at every iteration in the while loop. So I moved it into the while loop.